# Get Max for field in SQL according to the datatype

Tags: sql, select, sql-server-2008-r2, max

I am trying to get the MAX of a field in SQL. The field takes numeric and non numeric characters. If the field has the values A, B, C the result should be C. But when the field has for example A, B, C, 1, 2 the result should be 2. 
Can someone please assist me on how I can achieve this??

Thank You

[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNNyZ.png)

Comment: Please tag the DBMS.

Comment: Is that several rows of data, or do you store comma separated values?

Comment: It is several rows of data

Comment: give one eg. and tried query

Comment: It is bacically a table with varchar field, if the field has the values:

ID    Value
1       A
2       B
3       C

Max will be C
But when the table get an numeric value:

ID    Value
4      1
5      2

Then the Max should be 2 and not the non numeric value C

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
SELECT TOP 1 IDValue
FROM
(
SELECT 'A' as IDValue, ISNUMERIC('A') tag
UNION
SELECT 'C', ISNUMERIC('C')
UNION
SELECT 'B', ISNUMERIC('B')
UNION
SELECT '1',ISNUMERIC('1')
UNION
SELECT '2',ISNUMERIC('2')
)tmp
ORDER BY tag DESC,IDValue DESC
```

### Output

2

[**ISNUMERIC()**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx) returns 1 if expression is number else 0 . You can use it in `ORDER BY` to fetch max value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this : May solve your problem at some level

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(data VARCHAR(2))
INSERT INTO @T VALUES('A'),('B'),('C'),('1'),('2')

SELECT TOP(1) data
FROM @T
ORDER BY CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(data)=1 
              THEN 'Z'+data
              ELSE data 
         END desc
```

Answer (score 0):

here's the syntax for finding max value with SQL

```
SELECT MAX(column_name) FROM table_name;
```

you could refer to http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_max.asp for further reading and code testing

Answer (score 0):

Do conditional ordering

```
select n from
(
select '1' as n union all
select '2' as n union all
select 'A' as n union all
select 'B' as n union all
select 'C' as n 
) t
order by case when isnumeric(n)=1 then 1 else 2 end,n desc



select n from
(
select 'A' as n union all
select 'B' as n union all
select 'C' as n 
) t
order by case when isnumeric(n)=1 then 1 else 2 end,n desc
```